# MIGLayout-Auto wrap to next line when available column is less than columnSpan of component

Tags: miglayout

My layout constraints are
new MigLayout("wrap 4")

Am trying to dynamically place components.

### Use Case

Even if the constraints for the component(Comp4) are specified as span 3 1, the component should be automatically added in the next row even though there is 1 column left because the column span(3) is greater than available column(1) in 1st row

are there any constraints which can specified to handle these kind of use cases?

Answer (score 0):

With `MigLayout("wrap 4")` you are using `wrap` as a container constraint. In this context, it is a convenience auto-wrapping constraint. If you have a layout that happens to have four cells per row that you can use it. If not, than you should use component `wrap` constraint. The container `wrap` is not meant to dynamically adapt itself.

Comment: Agreed. But in case of wrap constraint for the component, the component will be placed in the available cell(by shrinking the component) and then does the wrapping. Is there any constraint/API at component level which lays the component only if the available cell's dimension(columnSpan and rowSpan) is able to accommodate the requested component's columnSpan and rowSpan else available cells are skipped and the component is laid at next available area (where cells can be merged) which complies with the component's columnSpan and rowSpan

Comment: I don't think so. You can use API calls like getComponentConstraints(component) to get the constraint and programatically do what you want. But there is no such constraint that would do this automatically for you.